# What is the (double **) in front of a malloc mean?

Tags: c++

for example in this code:

```
double **Data, *DataT;
Data = (double **)malloc(3*sizeof(double *)+3*12*sizeof(double));
```

I just read that malloc allocates memory from the heap. But i could not find what that (double **) meant in front of the malloc.
There is a line of code directly after this as well that i have seen this in.

```
for (i = 0, DataT = (double *)(Data+3); i < 3; i++, DataT += 12)
```

Here there is a (double *) in front of Data+3

Could you please explain to me what that does?
Thank you

Comment: double** : pointer to (double pointer = double*)... :)

Comment: it's best to not use these with c++. Also casting is better done with `static_cast< double**>` syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`malloc()` returns type `void *`, while your pointer is of type `double *` or `double **`. The operator before malloc - looking like (type) - is the type conversion operator, needed to convert malloc's return value to the type of the pointer you are using.

Comment: why does one need to type-cast empty memory? I thought malloc just frees up space so whatever needs to fit inside Data could fit?

Comment: it is standard...  a pointer has a type in C and C++. e.g. : when you create an `int* p`, sizeof(*p) returns `4` or another number according to the architecture. if you want to put another type of date in p, you will have a warning or an error in compilation. malloc allocate memory space, it does not free it...

Comment: @user947659 because C++ is [strongly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing) so it has restrictions on operations involving different types. Since in C++ there is no implicit conversion from `void *` to `double **`, trying to assign a `void *` to a `double **` is a syntax error.

Comment: You want your pointers to correctly represent the types of memory that they point to so the compiler can do correct pointer arithmetic on them.

Answer (score 4):

`(double**)` is a cast. it says that the result of the malloc is changed to double**.

malloc returns `void*` according to the standard.

so it is casted to `double**` to be the same nature of `data` : double**.

but in C, there is no need to the cat because void * is casted implicitly. so you can write directly :

```
Data = malloc(3*sizeof(double *)+3*12*sizeof(double));
```

as your question is for C++, which is compatible with C `malloc`, you have to put the cast : `(double**)`.

so you can use `malloc` and the cast if you have a code that you want to use in programs in C and in C++. else, use `new` and `delete`...

Answer (score 2):

It's a **type cast**.  The rules for its syntax and usage should be a part of any C primer.  The definitive book for this kind of thing is [the one by Kernighan and Ritchie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).

Comment: why does one need to type-cast empty memory? I thought malloc just frees up space so whatever needs to fit inside Data could fit?

Comment: @user947659: As others have pointed out, you actually **don't** need to typecast the return value of `malloc()` in the C language.  In C, the type `void *` is implicitly convertible to any other pointer type.  However, in the C++ language, the type `void *` is *not* implicitly convertible, so you need a cast.  It's not a generally very good idea to mix C and C++ idioms.  If you're compiling your code as C++, then use the `new` and `delete` keywords instead of the `malloc()` and `free()` functions.  Conversely, if you're compiling your code as C, then don't cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2):

It means "pointer to a pointer".

Answer (score 2):

The `(double **)` is a casting operator. It casts the void pointer returned by malloc to a pointer to pointer to double.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pointer to a pointer. e.g. a double dereference.

```
c -> some memory address
*c -> whatever is at the memory address stored in c
**c -> whatever is at the memory address stored in *c
```

Answer (score 2):

The `(double**)` and `(double*)` are what are known as **C style casts**. These make whatever type is after them into the type inside the parentheses.

The first C style cast is turning the return type of malloc into `double**` so it can be stored in the `double**` variable.
The second cast is turning it into a `double*`, so it can be dereferenced correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`double**` means that you're allocating a pointer to a pointer of a double